# Is there a best way to demonstrate a 3D object in a 2D video?

Tags: 3d

I would like to make a video of a 3D object so that it can reflect its shape without information loss and for easier understanding.

Is there a conventional rule-of-thumb way to demonstrate the object with 2D video? (for example, will rotate around its major axis for 360$^\circ$ cause some trouble for 3D reconstruction?)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are conventions, but in the case of animation, I would do what is usually done in these cases: a storyboard.

Imagining the object enclosed in a cube we can see the six faces that surround it, counting the ceiling (3) and the floor (6):

[image]

Placing the cube on a plane is the basis for the storyboard:

[image]

Ideally, the camera should pan over each face of the cube. The animation script is what the sequence should look like, this depends on how you want to display the object in the final project.

[image]

If it were a personal project, I would do the animation as follow:

1. Starting with an isometric view of the object
2. The movement through each face without perspective
3. Ending with a 360º isometric view.

Comment: Cool! thank you for the sharing!